Why custom dialect output html code that is not processed further by standard dialect?
I try to use custom dialect in thymeleaf, in order to dynamically add extra informations display in included fragments when  context conditions are met. I would like to insert a div with a th:replace attribute, that will be processed by the standard dialect afterwards.
I succeed to create an AbstractElementTagProcessor, which include a new div with thymeleaf standard dialect attributes :
public class IncludeDisplayPathDivInFragmentModelProcessor extends AbstractElementTagProcessor {

    private static final String ATTR_NAME = "fragment";
    private static final String RAW_ATTR_NAME = "th:fragment";
    private static final int PRECEDENCE = 100;

    public IncludeDisplayPathDivInFragmentModelProcessor(final String dialectPrefix) {
        super(TemplateMode.HTML, // This processor will apply only to HTML mode
                dialectPrefix,     // Prefix to be applied to name for matching
                null,              // No tag name: match any tag name
                false,             // No prefix to be applied to tag name
                ATTR_NAME,         // Name of the attribute that will be matched
                true,              // Apply dialect prefix to attribute name
                PRECEDENCE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doProcess(ITemplateContext context, IProcessableElementTag tag, IElementTagStructureHandler structureHandler) {
        //avoid infinite recursion with included fragment
        String attributeValue = tag.getAttributeMap().get(RAW_ATTR_NAME);
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(attributeValue)) {
            return;
        }
        if(attributeValue.equals("catalogue-info") || attributeValue.equals("css")){
            return;
        }
        // The Model Factory will allow us to create new events
        final IModelFactory modelFactory = context.getModelFactory();
        IModel model = modelFactory.createModel();
        model.add(modelFactory.createOpenElementTag("div", "th:replace", "fragments/utils/catalogue-info.html :: catalogue-info"));
        model.add(modelFactory.createText("TEST"));
        model.add(modelFactory.createCloseElementTag("div"));
    
        structureHandler.insertImmediatelyAfter(model, true);
    }


I succeed to register the new dialect and generate in the final html :
 <div th:replace="fragments/utils/catalogue-info.html :: catalogue-info">TEST</div>

I do not understand why this code is not processed further by the standard dialect as the div is created as an "event", and the precedence of the custom dialect is the same of the standard dialect. Any hints ? Thanks by advance, hope that this question will be useful to others too :)
